# Elasticsearch get n ordered records and then apply grouping

Tags: elasticsearch

Here's an example of what I'm looking for. Let's say I have records of some purchases. I want to get records where price is > $50 and order by price descending. I want to limit those ordered records to 100 and then group them by zip code.

Final result should have counts of hits for each zip where sum of those counts would total to 100 record.

ES v2.1.1

Comment: Do you want to limit hits or limit the buckets size to 100? Do you want sorting on hits or on buckets

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-search.html) to get the 100 results and then post-process to perform the aggregation (since an aggregation of top hits cannot be done directly using the ES API).

- "I want to get records where price is > $50" - You need a [range filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ranges.html).
- "...order by price descending" - You need a [sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_sorting.html).
- "I want to limit those ordered records to 100" - You need to specify 
  the size parameter.
- "...then group them by zip code" - You need to post-process the "hits":"hits" array to do this (e.g. inserting into a hash table / dictionary with zip code as the key values).

For steps 1-3 you need:

```
    $ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/_search?pretty' -d '{"query":  
       {"filtered" : {"filter" : { "range": { "price": { "gt": 50 }}}}},

    "size" : 100,

    "sort": { "price": { "order": "desc" }}
    }'
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. Size parameter seems to be ignored and all hits from query are aggregated.

Comment: I just tested it and it worked perfectly (except for a missing colon after filtered which I've now fixed), returning the number given in size.

Comment: Hmm interesting. What version of ES?

Comment: I'm using version 2.1.1. By the way, the "hits":"total" parameter will specify the total matches so that may give more than 100, but only the size number of documents will be in the "hits":"hits" array.

Comment: Just to clarify in case there is misunderstanding my results returns hits object with 100 results and aggregation object that has zip buckets based on all hits instead of 100 hits.

Comment: Yes, sorry I've misunderstood what you wanted. Unfortunately, you cannot get what you want directly from the ES API, you need to post-process the results. I'll update my solution.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean by "group them by zip code":

1. just want to know the number of docs in the group?
2. a hash with zip code as the key associated with docs?

If 1:

```
{
    "size": 100,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "price": {
                        "gt": 50
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": {
        "price": "desc"
    },
    "aggs": {
        "by_zip_code": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "zip_code"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If 2, you may use the [top hits aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html). However, sorting by price is not possible (how could we do that?), and by default Elasticsearch uses the `_count` (check [intrinsic sorts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_intrinsic_sorts.html) out). If the sort is not a big deal, the following will work:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "price": {
                        "gt": 50
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": {
        "price": "desc"
    },
    "aggs": {
        "by_zip_code": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "zip_code",
                "size": 100
            },
            "aggs": {
                "hits": {
                    "top_hits": {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm interested in scenario 1 but your solution does not seem to work as all filtered hits are being aggregated (instead of only first 100 hits)

Comment: yep ;(
trying to figure out, it seems to not be trivial as aggregations ignore the `size` option...